# jfreechart itext: put multiple charts in one pdf

Tags: java, itext, jfreechart

How can I put multiple JfreeCharts in to one pdf? There are plenty of examples how to put 1 JfreeChart in to a pdf but I can't find any on how to put multiple JfreeCharts in to 1 pdf.

Some of the JfreeCharts should should go next to each other and others should go below each other.

Answer (score 3):

There's an example in my book: http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=262

As you can see, I have two different charts, a pie chart and a bar chart. I draw these charts to a `PdfTemplate` object. I then add the templates to a canvas using an X,Y coordinate (this allows you to add them next to each other or below each other).

Another option, is to wrap the `PdfTemplate` objects inside `Image` objects, and position these images for instance using a `PdfPTable`.

Comment: Please, how could I edit Your code to put one chart on one page and second chart on second page? Thank You very much.

Comment: The link is broken; is there another URL for accessing the mentioned example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on Lowagie's answer. It's better to use `PdfPCellEvent` interface.

```
public class JFreeChartEvent implements PdfPCellEvent {
    private JFreeChart chart;

    public JFreeChartEvent(final JFreeChart chart){
        this.chart = chart;
    }

    @Override
    public void cellLayout(PdfPCell arg0, Rectangle arg1, PdfContentByte[] arg2) {
        PdfContentByte cb = arg2[PdfPTable.TEXTCANVAS]; //optional, can be other canvas
        PdfTemplate pie = cb.createTemplate(arg1.getWidth(), arg1.getHeight());
        Graphics2D g2d1 = new PdfGraphics2D(pie, arg1.getWidth(), arg1.getHeight());
        Rectangle2D r2d1 = new Rectangle2D.Double(0, 0, arg1.getWidth(), arg1.getHeight());
        chart.draw(g2d1, r2d1);
        g2d1.dispose();
        cb.addTemplate(pie, arg1.getLeft(), arg1.getBottom());
    }
}
```

While using `PdfPCell`,

```
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();    
cell.setCellEvent(new JFreeChartEvent(getChart());
cell.setFixedHeight(300.f);   //height must be set if its row's height is not defined yet
```